# WPF adding custom ContextMenu to a view referenced in another view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What I'm trying to accomplish is placing a context menu to a listbox item that is referenced in another view as such:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foo.Bar.MyTestApp.Views.ListBoxPresenterView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar.MyTestApp.Views">
    <Grid>
        
        <views:MyListBoxView />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This displays my MyListBoxView.xaml just fine. However, what I want to know is if its possible to add a context menu to views:MyListBoxView from ListBoxPresenterView.xaml. Reason being is that I just want to keep MyListBoxView.xaml as generic as possible. So if I want to do any kind of special modifications to it, then let it be only in the classes that reference it.

so essentially it would be something like:

```
<views:MyListBoxView >
<style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
... add context menu to a list box item template
</ListBox>
<views:MyListBoxView />
```

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `<views:MyListBoxView />` exactly?

Comment: @mm8 u UserControl that contains a ListBox control, and some textboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MyListBoxView` is indeed a `ListView`, you could set its or its item containers' `ContextMenu` as usual:

```
<views:MyListBoxView>
    <views:MyListBoxView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </views:MyListBoxView.ItemContainerStyle>
</views:MyListBoxView>
```

If it is a `UserControl`, you could add a dependency property to the `UserControl` and then to it in the XAML markup of `MyListBoxView`.

**ListBoxPresenterView:**

```
<views:MyListBoxView ItemContextMenu="..." />
```

**MyListBoxView:**

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu"
    Value="{Binding ItemContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```